# Display file name when button is clicked?

Tags: python

I am making a music player for my first python project. How do I make it so when I press the skip file or when a music is played, a new label is created stating the name of the file?
Eg. Skip is pressed and it says 'music.mp3 is now playing'.
OR File is loaded and it states 'music.mp3 is now playing'.

This is the function I want when the button plays except I need it to gather the name of the file and use it as a variable:

```
my_label = Label(win, text='', bg="#0d0e0e", fg="white")
my_label.place(x=450, y=5)
def label_change():
    my_label.config(text='SONG HAS BEEN SKIPPED!')
label_change()
```

Here's the skip function:

```
def next(self):
    self.file_path = (self.music_file.rsplit("/",1))[0].replace("/","\\")
    if "/" in self.music_file:
        self.file_name = self.music_file.rsplit("/",1)[1]
    else:
        self.file_name = self.music_file

self.filenames = next(walk(self.file_path), (None, None, []))[2]
self.file_count = 0

for i in self.filenames:
    if i == self.file_name:
        break
    self.file_count += 1

self.next_file = self.file_count + 1
self.directory_limit = len(self.filenames)
if self.next_file == self.directory_limit:
    self.next_file = 0
self.music_file = self.file_path + "/" + self.filenames[self.next_file]
self.file_count = 0
mixer.init()
try:
    mixer.music.load(self.music_file)
except pygame.error as message:
    while True:
        self.next_file += 1
        if self.next_file == self.directory_limit:
            self.next_file = 0
        self.music_file = self.file_path + "/" + self.filenames[self.next_file]
        self.file_extension = self.music_file.rsplit(".",1)[1]
        if (".wav") or (".mp3") in self.file_extension:
            mixer.music.load(self.music_file)
            break

mixer.music.play()
```

Here is what the GUI Looks like at the moment:
[image]

And in case the LOAD function is needed:

```
load_button = Button(win, text='Load', width=55, height = 55, font=("Arial", 10), command=self.load, image = self.login_btn, bg = 'white', borderwidth = 0, highlightthickness=0)
load_button.place(x=50,y=250, anchor='center')

def load(self):
    self.music_file = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="/AIT Python 1/Assets", title="Select a song", filetypes=(("wav files", "*.wav"),("all files", "*.*"),("mp3 files", "*.mp3")))
    print("Loaded:", self.music_file)
    self.play_restart.set('Play')
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some things missing in your code. It looks like you're using classes, so store the name of the file in a variable (the self.music_file in your load function).

Try to use some debugger tool like the debug of VScode, so you can inspect your objects and the value of the variables.